# Strange Addition

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

### Challenge

Calculate the strange sum of two natural numbers (also known as lunar addition):

Given \$A=...a_2 a_1 a_0\$ and \$B=... b_2 b_1 b_0\$ two natural numbers written in the decimal base, the **strange sum** is defined, based on the **maximum** operation, as:
\$A+B=... \max(a_2,b_2) \max(a_1,b_1) \max(a_0,b_0)\$

```
   ...         a2         a1         a0
 + ...         b2         b1         b0
 ----------------------------------------
   ...  max(a2,b2) max(a1,b1) max(a0,b0)
```

### Input

Two natural numbers

All the following is allowed:

- Zero-padded strings (same length)
- Left-space-padded strings
- Right-space-padded strings
- Array of two padded strings
- 2D space-padded char array

### Output

A natural numbers

### Example

```
1999 + 2018 -> 2999
17210 + 701 -> 17711
32 + 17     -> 37
308 + 250   -> 358
308 + 25    -> 328
```

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963) (choose the most appropriate format for your language/solution).
- No need to handle **negative** values or **invalid input**
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: also known as [lunar addition](https://youtu.be/cZkGeR9CWbk)

Comment: Can we take the input as zero-padded strings (same length)?

Comment: I think this is a bit too trivial. Weird that has not been asked before

Comment: Can we get/output lists of digits?

Comment: Can we have the numbers in the same length? Like 17210 00701 instead of 17210 701 ?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer see first rule

Comment: @mdahmoune Yeah, would it be convenient enough?

Comment: @mdahmoune can we take the input as two numbers in the same length, with leading zeroes in the second one?

Comment: @WindmillCookies the challenge is more interesting when no zeros fill

Comment: Are leading spaces in the output allowed?

Comment: @BMO yes it is ok leading spaces in the output

Comment: I fail to see what input formats are allowed exactly. The input format is very important in this challenge, as some formats allow much easier processing. What of the following are allowed? 1) Zero-padded strings (same length) 2) Left-space-padded strings 3) Right-space-padded strings. 4) Array of two padded strings. 5) 2D space-padded char array. Voting to close and downvoting for now; I will happily remove my votes when solved

Comment: @LuisMendo choose the most appropriate format for your language

Comment: @mdahmoune Above you say that input as zero-padded strings is disallowed. Here you say zero-padded strings and space-padded char arrays are both allowed. Which is it?

Comment: @lirtosiast I only said that the challenge is more interesting with no padding

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda*a:map(max,*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSvRKjexQCM3sUJHK1Hzf0FRZl6JQppGZl5BaYmGpg6U1vwfbaijYK6jYKSjAGQYxHJFGwApsBCQNIwFAA)

I/O as 0-pre-padded lists of digits.

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7v///0cb6iiY6ygY6SgAGQax/6MNgBRYCEgaxgIA)

I/O as 0-pre-padded lists of digits.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 65 bytes

```r
function(x)apply(outer(x,10^(max(nchar(x)):1-1),`%/%`)%%10,2,max)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEAXQq7QR5sNETquMzhKKJAWlIQZ2emv5eLmFbulbeKIvR4pU4e77fCk9ZctUWfRKl6sU/e5@A7P0ArZqUBZKieaR/0cL5EmMMdyNWiagfQ)

Input as integers, output as list of digits.

If zero-padding lists of digits was allowed, then simply `pmax` would suffice.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
X>
```

> Choose the most appropriate format for your language/solution

The input format is: 2D char array of two rows, each corresponding to a line, with the shorter number left-padded with spaces. For example

```
17210
  701
```

which in MATL is defined as

```
['17210'; '  701']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8Lu//9odUNzI0MDdWsFdQUFcwND9VgA)

#### Explanation

```
      % Implicit input: 2D char array with two rows 
X>    % Take maximum of (code points of) each column
      % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>73</s> <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:map(max,zip(a.rjust(len(b)),b.rjust(len(a))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczPCsIwDAbwu08R8JAWOmkyRjtBn8RLiw4n@1PmBPXla@dlm/jdku@XhNd47TuO1eEUG9f6swOn/L51QbTuqd51EG433B73UTSXTngplV/MTqbEMNTdCJVAKssSQQGyJosStgBZdoQUTs1mdoZJowJAo2npyBii2eWMaZkcpJPVv4kunLb4dciFXru8sH/cBH8c2/gB)

Takes input as two strings, and returns a list of digits

---

Alternative:

Takes input as two integers; same output

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```python
lambda*i:map(max,zip(*['%*d'%(len(`max(i)`),v)for v in i]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczRCoIwFMbx@57iQIjbmLAzkc2gXqQCFyYNdA4RqV5@LS9M6dx9f34c/xofvZOhOV5Ca7pbbZg9dMaTzjz523rCzmnC6jQh7d2RKlZiaUX5RJt@gAmsA3ulNPjBuhEagmVZAgcpUFPYA2TZCeLJmHeLURIFB1ACVwaVQlxMLmPic17/@e6fEXo2shAbkxf6z0S0NVKHDw)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 10, <s>78</s> 57 bytes

```java
a->b->{for(int i=a.length;i-->0;)if(a[i]<b[i])a[i]=b[i];}
```

Input as two space-padded character arrays.

Modifies the first input-array instead of returning a new one to save 21 bytes (thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bZBBj4IwEIXv/ooJp5JAU9gYJCiJMdnbnjwaD0MFrWIhMLgxxt/OFmiy68ZL8/rea@fLnPGG/vlw6WWJbQtfqPRjBtASkpJwNinvSJW86LQkVWn@acVSnrDZ7b13nU2l2@6aN7aTplDACnr008xPH0XVMKUJ1Ap5mesjnRLl@6lIXFUw3Kn9MjOHO6jVoJJnn8wMU91lpWGyaLdKHeBqcNmWGqWPuz2gO6ADUN4Sc4I4jh0PnFAEC8dN/iZRGIghAohE8Jp9hEMQRP9csRi/mou3PoTzyX/Ofnc3Ao61CRDQA6sgs6TTfmBttoOcqo25rpsG78xOKTjWdXlna5ejlHlNLHut2d723lJ@5VVHvDYTqNRM5992nHlt4Z79Dw)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->{            // Method with two char-array parameters and String return-type
  for(int i=a.length;i-->0;)
                   //  Loop `i` in the range (length, 0]:
    if(a[i]<b[i])  //   If the `i`'th character in input `a` is smaller than in input `b`:
      a[i]=b[i];}  //    Change the `i`'th character in `a` to the `i`'th character of `b`
```

Comment: `a->b->{for(int i=a.length;i-->0;)if(a[i]<b[i])a[i]=b[i];}` ([57 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZBBj4IwEIXv/ooJp5JAU9gYJCiJMdnbnjwaD0MFrWIhMLgxxt/OFmiy68ZL8/rea@fLnPGG/vlw6WWJbQtfqPRjBtASkpJwNinvSJW86LQkVWn@acVSnrDZ7b13nU2l2@6aN7aTplDACnr008xPH0XVMKUJ1Ap5mesjnRLl@6lIXFUw3Kn9MjOHO6jVoJJnn8wMU91lpWGyaLdKHeBqcNmWGqWPuz2gO6ADUN4Sc4I4jh0PnFAEC8dN/iZRGIghAohE8Jp9hEMQRP9csRi/mou3PoTzyX/Ofnc3Ao61CRDQA6sgs6TTfmBttoOcqo25rpsG78xOKTjWdXlna5ejlHlNLHut2d723lJ@5VVHvDYTqNRM5992nHlt4Z79Dw)). Reuse `a` as output to gain much, much bytes.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, can't believe I hadn't thought of that. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>14</strike>  12 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Jonah

```
(>./@,:)&.|.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYy9CoNAEIT7e4ohhT@gmz1F1APFdwlZQpoUtsmzX0ZPK5lmdr6PfUdbJ4EiQGMxy32pQpnJV2LpboLcJslR4Rdgq3PPx@uDBuOeOsAf1TgqryEZHj3jmd3pST25sdFKTsuDtCWzzTnXDkPalWX720FP1lxY/AM)

Input and output as list(s) of digits

Comment: 12 bytes: `(>./@,:)&.|.`.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYy9CoNAEIT7e4ohhT@gmz1F1APFdwlZQpoUtsmzX0ZPK5lmdr6PfUdbJ4EiQGMxy32pQpnJV2LpboLcJslR4Rdgq3PPx@uDBuOeOsAf1TgqryEZHj3jmd3pST25sdFKTsuDtCWzzTnXDkPalWX720FP1lxY/AM "J – Try It Online")

Comment: if you’re looking for a challenge, see if you can improve this monstrosity: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175968/15469

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9 6</s> 5 bytes

-3 thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)
-1 thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

```
íζ€àR
```

Takes input as a list of lists of digits

```
í      # Reverse both inputs
 ζ     # Zip
  €à   # Keep the bigger digits
    R  # Reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Npz2x41rTm8IOj//@hoQx1LEIzViTbSMdAx1LGIjQUA) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q9v/w2nPbHjWtObwg6L/O/@hoQx1LEIzViTbSMdAx1LGIjeUCiZrrGAF5BkBxc5A4WNRYxwjIB8pBeQZA1SB9pkB1aCKxsQA)

Comment: `€R` can be `í`. Also, I don't think you need `€þ` as `number > space`

Comment: @Emigna Thanks! I thought I tried it without `€þ` and it didn't work, but now it does...

Comment: Do you need the `J` at the end?

Comment: @Shaggy No, I guess I don't. Thanks!

Comment: It's lame, but the rules allow a [3 byte solution](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q9v/ctkdNaw4v@K/zPzraUMcSBGN1oo10DHQMdSxiY7lAouY6RkCeAVBcSUFJB4TNQfJgWWMdI6A4UA2UZwDUBdJvClSPLALSBRSNjQUA) by taking a 2D space-padded char array..

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Takes input as an array of digit arrays.

```
mÔÕÔËrw
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=bdTV1Mtydw==&input=WwpbMSw3LDIsMSwwXQpbNywwLDFdCl0KLVE=)

```
m            :Map
 Ô           :  Reverse
  Õ          :Transpose
   Ô         :Reverse
    Ë        :Map
     r       :  Reduce by
      w      :  Maximum
```

---

If taking zero-padded arrays as input is permitted (it would currently fall under a "convenient format" but I suspect that's not the challenger's intent) then this can be 3 bytes.

```
íwV
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=7XdW&input=WzEsNywyLDEsMF0KWzAsMCw3LDAsMV0KLVE=)

```
í       :Interleave the first input
  V     :With the second
 w      :Reduce each pair by maximum
```

Comment: [Here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=bdR5X3J3w3c=&input=W1sxLDcsMiwxLDBdLFs3LDAsMV1dCi1R)'s another 8 byte solution with a different strategy and simpler input format. maybe you can shave a byte from that?

Comment: @KamilDrakari: Uncanny - I was just updating with the exact same solution!

Comment: Interestingly, the version that separates the "transpose" and "reduce" steps is [also 8 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=bdTVrnJ3w9Q=&input=WwpbMSw3LDIsMSwwXQpbNywwLDFdCl0KLVE=) because of better shortcuts

Comment: @KamilDrakari, oh, we have a shortcut for `y` now? I did not know that. [Here's another way](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=bdR5cid3INQ=&input=WwpbMSw3LDIsMSwwXQpbNywwLDFdCl0KLVE=), also 8 bytes.

Comment: Ooh, that's a neat trick with `'`. I don't know whether that would ever save bytes, but it's definitely cool.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
a#b=zipWith max(p b++a)$p a++b
p=(' '<$)
```

Input/output as strings, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BC4IwAIXv@xWPElSWsSmhguvStU4dOkTERkMlnUMXRfTfLavD4/E9vsOr5HDVTTOOcq7Es7aH2lVo5SOwUJTK0LOQlCpiReDDL7xwbGVtID6O3Z1RdliiqY0eIIoCpXabzjht3IB7pXtNMCmNwQtHuVAnFBHuXX8Zpk3A3tze9VsDDxKUYoZvKNSPovUPg8@7cOR5niNmPCM8jTlDyjhJYvCUJCxDvGL/fgM)

#### Explanation

The function `p` replaces each character by a space, using `p b++a` and `p a++b` are thus the same length. This way we can use `zipWith` without losing any elements, using `max` with it works because a  (space) has lower codepoint than any of the characters `['0'..'9']`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 37 bytes

```
{[R~] roundrobin($_».reverse)».max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsIwFEXRrTyKiKKUn4imAdtFOC1FWk1AMI2kKJYQN@bMjcXYibNz4d6Uu@6iGTHXKKOvD68Gzt77s7PdpV/Mjp937tRDuUEtE037DHFoR2Q@r6kJWCGBJZTwGtN@sqYLGbR12DMpJTixolqnEJwRBLFfbDiYmEAF@Jb@rOIX)

Takes input as a list of lists of digits.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
{[~] [Zmax] $_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcrRCoIwAIXhVzkMyw1jbIuag9yDJCJWDoqWYV0koq@@Zjfdff/hPNv@vg9@wNqhCGM5VyiPvvlUSOopvJoB/NZdHzRFhpTNBAXI7GhSW8udf1OyGjMe//zc@dN0ISzuCxlc1@MgjTFQQuZ2E0MrKaCFXGKrIPUPIofaiT9t@AI)

Takes input as a list of space padded arrays of characters, though for this challenge the lax input format makes it rather boring. Alternatively, here's the program that takes a list of two integers instead:

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 41 bytes

```perl6
{+[~] [Zmax] $_>>.fmt("%{.max}d")>>.comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxLCsIwGAav8hHUtlTCn4imAZuDWIrUR0AxRqoLS2muHqMbdzOzmMe5v22iG7CwqONYNqFFs3Pdu8Vsbwy37pWz@chTmU6sSOXo3WGKz24Av/rLPc9QIisCQw0WeNpY32MrtNaQJCqzTKKkICgSX1lJCPUDqiDX9EcTPw)

If you don't mind a huge amount of whitespace, you can also remove the `+` from the front.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                       }  # Anonymous code block
             $_>>    # Map each integer to 
                 .fmt("%{.max}d") # The number padded by the max of the list spaces
                                 >>.comb   # And split each to list of characters
      [Zmax]  # Get the max of each digit at each index
              # This works because space is coerced to 0
              # Otherwise we would have to add a 0 to the formatting string
  [~]   # Join the list of digits and spaces
 +      # And coerce the string to a number to get rid of leading whitespace
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

*NB: This answer was posted before the loose I/O formats were explicitly allowed. With zero-padded arrays of digits, this can be done in [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc7BDoMgDAbg@56CIySdAsYgS2APQjyg08VFwcxlr8/owcNm1h566df@D//2W/@c1tc5xNuQRpO8sZ2xvlj8SmmAiRkbbOem9houOFjqY9jiPBRzvNOROgEau2XUSeAgoGkZI1hlSYjUWp8OQoHMixwNz0ahQ5WFUEqIX1GBxN0M99t74Q9CKnUUHINgphofsW9R1c1fwXO4@ihkkz4), (but is much less interesting, IMHO).*

Takes input as two integers. Returns an integer.

```javascript
f=(a,b,t=10)=>a|b&&(a%t<b%t?b:a)%t+t*f(a/t,b/t)|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1BDoIwEAXQvaeYDaTVajslpMWInqVFMBpCjUxccfdaYEec5f8vf17u68bm83zTcQj3NsauZk54QTUqXl/d5POcuYwuPqObPzue0YH2HXOShJfEJxWbMIyhb099eLCOYVVVArRCyzlICaBTsNsYo1EJMApXg8YgbkyhRcpTP9@8A1CYrVE2vSrVohZTlPa/WYdWo238AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                     // f = recursive function taking:
  a,                      //   a = first integer
  b,                      //   b = second integer
  t = 10                  //   t = 10 (which is used 6 times below)
) =>                      //
  a | b                   // bitwise OR between a and b to test whether at least one of
                          // them still has an integer part
  &&                      // if not, stop recursion; otherwise:
  (                       //
    a % t < b % t ? b : a // if a % 10 is less than b % 10: use b; otherwise: use a
  ) % t +                 // isolate the last decimal digit of the selected number
  t *                     // add 10 times the result of
  f(a / t, b / t)         // a recursive call with a / 10 and b / 10
  | 0                     // bitwise OR with 0 to isolate the integer part
```

#### Alternate version

Same I/O format.

```javascript
f=(a,b)=>a|b&&[f(a/10,b/10)]+(a%10<b%10?b:a)%10|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BDoIwDAbgu0/Ri2SLU9YRsmFEH8R46BCIhjAjxhPvPgvciD20Sfvl75O@NFTvx@uz78O9jrEpBSkvyzONPkmujaAUtfLc5G0naIv65Lld/JEkz1HHKvRD6OpDF1rRCCyKQoHR6KSENAUwvNisjDWcCVbjYtBaxJXJjOI936eacgAyuzba8atcz2o2We7@myVoMcbFHw)

Comment: You can get much shorter if you assume your input to be a 2d space padded char array.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some explanation? I ""tried"" to do this challenge in JavaScript but I failed and would like to see how your solution works :)

Comment: @Neyt I've added a commented version. The alternate version is using the same logic; the only difference is that we add the next digit to the left as a string instead of multiplying the result of the recursive call by 10.

Comment: @Arnauld Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 53 bytes

```
s=lambda p,q:p+q and 10*s(p//10,q//10)+max(p%10,q%10)
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Nice Answer. Writing answers is simpler when you host them on [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g2JzE3KSVRoUCn0KpAu1AhMS9FwdBAq1ijQF/f0ECnEERqaucmVmgUqIL4QELzf0FRZl6JRrGGoaWlpY6RgaGFpuZ/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 156 bytes

```
proc S a\ b {join [lmap x [split [format %0[set l [expr max([string le $a],[string le $b])]]d $a] ""] y [split [format %0$l\d $b] ""] {expr max($x,$y)}] ""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCoMwEITveYqhpFDBQ6IU9Tk8xhziT4slatAUIuKzW2NLKXRP384uM2MrvW1mHCrkUAVKLI@h7SF0pwwcxGR0ayFuw9gpizMTU2OhIRpnRnTKXcRkx7a/QzegSoa/aykDKWsv43SSmP/dqC5q/3fcl68ndSGdg9XL63Y0eVcjPMsyRIynhCcRZ0gYJ3EEPzwhMUt3iK7sQzuSFYt52gki33v4qHV7AQ)

Not very golfy, but I had to give a try on it. Will golf it later!

Comment: **Tcl, 159 bytes** [Failed outgolf](https://tio.run/##TY9NCoMwFIT3OcUgKbTgIokUdesVXMYsorXFEn9IUlDEs1u1pfRt3jeLYWZ8ZdZ1sH2FHLpAifkQGUwBh9kNpvGQ99622uPEqCluoE4hCBby7JsO0rR6wAiZQbraw0DW42DR6vEsnbdN94CpQbUK/2WpLkrtD9Nupebg@WelY0iny3IErUfEpx3haZpCMJ4QHgvOEDNOIoH9eEwilmwgruxLG5Jl2/TyDjLfWuwxy/oG)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 120 bytes

```
@set/aw=1,x=%1,y=%2,z=0
@for /l %%i in (0,1,9)do @set/a"z+=w*((v=y%%10)+(v-=x%%10)*(v>>4)),y/=10,x/=10,w*=10
@echo %z%
```

Takes input as command-line parameters. 188-byte version works on arbitrary length integers:

```
@set/px=
@set/py=
@set z=
:l
@if %x:~-1% gtr %y:~-1% (set z=%x:~-1%%z%)else set z=%y:~-1%%z%
@set x=%x:~,-1%
@set y=%y:~,-1%
@if "%x%" neq "" if "%y%" neq "" goto l
@echo %x%%y%%z%
```

Takes input on STDIN.

Answer (score 2):

## [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), 125 bytes

When I saw this challenge, I though: "let me use a template language! sure is a good fit"

I was wrong ... so wrong .... ... But was fun!

```
{%macro a(a,b,s='')%}{%for k,x in a|reverse|split('')%}{%set s=max(x,(b|reverse|split('')[k]))~s%}{%endfor%}{{s}}{%endmacro%}
```

This requires that "strict_variables" is set to `false` (default value).

To use this macro, you can do like this:

```
{% import 'file.twig' as my_macro %}

{{ my_macro.a(195,67) }}
```

Should display 167.

You can try this in https://twigfiddle.com/rg0biy
("strict_variables" set to off, it is on by default on the website)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
↔¤żY↔
```

Conveniently takes input/output as list of digits, [try it online](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HblENLju6JBNL///@PNtQx1zHSMdQxiP0fba5joGMYCwA) or [verify all!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq3Foeb52graSgq6dgpKGl5KCtoJSuaZGccqh5YeWPGpqzE8petQ24VHbpHJNzUPb/j9qm3JoydE9kUD6////hpaWlgpGBoYWXIbmRoYGCuYGhlzGRgqG5lzGBhYKRqYGUBoA)

### Explanation

```
↔¤żY↔  -- example inputs [1,4] [3,2]
 ¤  ↔  -- reverse the arguments of: [4,1] [2,3]
  żY   -- | zipWith (keeping elements of longer) max: [4,3]
↔      -- reverse: [3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
|>E:o
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C%3EE%3Ao&i=[%221999%22+%222018%22]%0A[%2217210%22+%22701%22]%0A[%2232%22+%2217%22]%0A[%22308%22+%22250%22]%0A[%22308%22+%2225%22]&a=1&m=2)

This program takes input as an array of strings.

```
|>  Right align inputs (filling with \0)
E   "Explode" array onto stack separately
:o  "Overlay" Keep the maximum element respective element from two arrays.
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C%3EE%3Ao&i=[%221999%22+%222018%22]%0A[%2217210%22+%22701%22]%0A[%2232%22+%2217%22]%0A[%22308%22+%22250%22]%0A[%22308%22+%2225%22]&a=1&m=2)

This is the first time I've seen a use for the overlay instruction "in the wild".

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 153 bytes

```
	X =INPUT
	Y =INPUT
	Y =DUPL(0,SIZE(X) - SIZE(Y)) Y
S	X LEN(1) . A REM . X	:F(O)
	Y LEN(1) . B REM . Y
	O =O GT(A,B) A	:S(S)
	O =O B	:(S)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NCsIwEITPm6fY4y7UUv9AAj0kNEqhJsWkkHj0LPbg@xNTKeJpZr5hmPdrfszPQ84Qse3tOAUB6d910zhQU/n@bigybvDrEjMm4ctoMJa2jDUqvJlr0QjyTI6X8a/Ta5cEOGwdXgKpSjMqkJ48r1SDXIIDN4VyX5Awtst535zE7vgB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 39 bytes

```
+`^(.*)(.)¶(.*)(.)
$1¶$3¶$2$4
%O`.
¶.?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg8187IU5DT0tTQ0/z0DYog0vF8NA2FWMgNlIx4VL1T9DjOrRNz57r/39DS0tLHSMDQwsuQ3MjQwMdBQVzA0MuYyMdQ3MuYwMLHSNTAzCtYGQKAA) Link includes test suite. Previous 45-byte [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1 version accepts unpadded strings:

```
P^`.+
+`^(.*)(.)¶(.*)(.)
$1¶$3¶$2$4
%O`.
¶.?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcYxCoAwDEDRPeeoUDWEJFVqJ4@g4C51cHBxEM/WA/Ri1aHD5/3nfK/7kNLYLWJZ90g99HG31LWW2pzqgJGcjPtTM0CzRIKcaIZSJISAyjKBeBVGzwJOUTw4nlBHrn4) Link includes test suite. Explanation:

```
P^`.+
```

Pad both values to the same length. (Retina 1 only. There are ways of emulating this in Retina 0.8.2 but they are not very golfy.)

```
+`^(.*)(.)¶(.*)(.)
$1¶$3¶$2$4
```

Transpose the values.

```
%O`.
```

Sort each pair into order.

```
¶.?
```

Delete all the low digits and surplus newlines.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
⭆θ⌈⟦ι§ηκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBTqKPgmVmTmluZqRGfqKDiWeOalpFZoZOgoZGvGampqWv//b2huZGjApaBgbmD4X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ          First input
⭆           Map over characters and join
  ⌈         Maximum of
   ⟦        List of
    ι       Current character of first input and
      η     Second input
     §      Indexed by
       κ    Current index
            Implicitly print
```

10-byte version "adds" any number of padded strings:

```
⭆§θ⁰⌈Ｅθ§λκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaDiWeOalpFZoFOooGGjqKPgmVmTmluZqgKSAQjDZHB2FbE0QsP7/PzqaS8nQ3MjQQEmHS0lBwdzAEMIwNrCAMBSMTJW4YmP/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Previous 14-byte version accepts unpadded strings:

```
⭆◧θＬη⌈⟦ι§◧ηＬθκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaAQkpvikppVoFOoo@KTmpZdkaGRoauoo@CZWZOaW5mpEZ@ooOJZ45qWkVsCVZsCVFoKUZsdqampa//9vaG5kaMBlbmD4X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ             First input
 ◧              Padded to
   Ｌ            Length of
    η           Second input
⭆               Map over characters and join
     ⌈          Maximum of
      ⟦         List of
       ι        Current character of first input and
          η     Second input
         ◧      Padded to
           Ｌ    Length of
            θ   First input
        §       Indexed by
             κ  Current index
                Implicitly print
```

17-byte version "adds" any number of strings:

```
≔⌈ＥθＬιη⭆η⌈Ｅθ§◧ληκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DN7EiM7c0F0gXaBTqKPik5qWXZGhkampq6ihkaFpzBRRl5pVoBJcAqXSQmgwdBTQtjiWeeSmpFRoBiSk@qWklGjkgjToK2ZogYP3/f3Q0l5KhuZGhgZIOl5K5gSGIMjawAFFGpkpcsbH/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: The question has been changed so the strings can be input as padded

Comment: Nitpicking, but you missed a close paren in the first verbose version :P

Comment: @ASCII-only If only TIO matched parens for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
meSdC
```

Takes input as array of two space-padded strings.

```
meSd       map greatest
    C      on the transpose of input
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=meSdC&input=%5B%271999%27%2C%272018%27%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%271999%27%2C%272018%27%5D%0A%5B%2717210%27%2C%27++701%27%5D%0A%5B%2732%27%2C%2717%27%5D%0A%5B%27308%27%2C%27250%27%5D%0A%5B%27308%27%2C%27+25%27%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet), 57 bytes

```
a=>b=>a.Select((x,i)=>a[i]>b[i]?x:b[i])
```

*-1 bytes by adding currying*

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jY5PSwMxEMXv@RQhpwTWkO2lrtuNh6KiKIg9eBAP2XTUQJpgkpWK9LOviV3EPwjOYYbHG37v6XigfYBxiMY94tVrTLBp0VfFl95a0Ml4F/92@Bk4CEb/@Lg07rlF2qoY8TV@QzhPTCoZjV@8WeMrZRxlk1HmdHB6EVPIjOqbOD9xwwaC6i0s9JMKUkr8kH3c4VF1su@k4isodSjdVoZlfWfuZZ/X8faoHDa26DNnmTt7C/w2mAS5JdB9Dr/wuREhVWFTUjdNQxglM1EfEsZY@38AngjzWS0KQoi5qPeMX5AbUOsPxhSwQ7vxHQ)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes when you use `x` instead of `a[i]` in condition

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

Input is taken as a an array of two 0-padded number arrays.

```
y_rw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vzK@qPz//2iuaEMdcx0jHUMdg1gdrmgDHQMg10DHMJYrlotLNwAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ceylon, 55 / 99

With 0- or space-padded strings of same length (returning an iterable of characters):

```ceylon
function t(String a,String b)=>zipPairs(a,b).map(max);
```

With 0- or space-padded strings (returning a String):

```ceylon
String t(String a,String b)=>String(zipPairs(a,b).map(max));
```

With strings of possibly different length (returning a String):

```ceylon
String u(String a,String b)=>String(zipPairs(a.padLeading(b.size),b.padLeading(a.size)).map(max));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.zip(b).map &:max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6Ua8qs0AjSVMvN7FAQc0qN7Gi9j9Q3Dba0NzI0EBHwdzAMBYkV12TUqOhpGpgmqKkmqKpl5yRWFQMEtdQsyrJj8/UrOUqUADq00mLBpKxeln5mXl6IIn/AA)

Pre-padded list blah blah. (Although it feels a little like cheating.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 74 bytes

```
Fn.new{|i|(0...i.count/2).map{|j|i[j]>i[j+i.count/2]?i[j]:i[j+i.count/2]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiazRsNAT08vUy85vzSvRN9IUy83saC6JqsmMzor1g5IaMOlYu1BYlaoYrW1/4Mri0tSc/UKijLzShxzcjRAVuglJwJZ0YY6CuY6CkY6CkCGgQ6XAm5gAFIAUgwkDWM1Nf8DAA)

Input is a single list of the two operands, e.g.

```
[1, 7, 2, 1, 0,
 0, 0, 7, 0, 1]
```

### Explanation

Now I need to figure out a formula for maximum.

```
Fn.new{|i|                                                               } // New anonymous function with the operand i
          (0...i.count/2)                                                  // Define an exclusive range from 0 to half the input
                         .map{|j|                                       }  // Turn every item of the list into ...
                                 i[j]>i[j+i.count/2]?i[j]:i[j+i.count/2]   // ... The maximum between i[j] and i[j+i.count/2]
                                                                           // (which is simply the other list's index at the same position)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=max -F`, 22 bytes

```perl
say map{max $_,getc}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7GgOjexQkElXic9tSS51sHt/38DQwMjLiMDQ@N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31gKJA2iezuMTKKrQkM8cWqO2/rhsA)

Input must be 0 or space padded so that the entries are the same length.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 51 chars, 102 bytes

```
{k←⌈/≢¨(a b)←⍎¨∘⍕¨⍺⍵⋄f←{((k-≢⍵)⍴0),⍵}⋄10⊥(f a)⌈f b}
```

test:

```
  h←{k←⌈/≢¨(a b)←⍎¨∘⍕¨⍺⍵⋄f←{((k-≢⍵)⍴0),⍵}⋄10⊥(f a)⌈f b}
  1999 h 2018
2999
  17210 h 701
17711
  32 h 17
37
  308 h 250
358
  308 h 25
328
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
{aGTb?ab}MZab
```

Maps zipped pairs of the two inputs and then returns the greater one.

Inputs must be padded with spaces.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/OtE9JMk@ManWNyox6f///4bmRoYG/xUUzA0MAQ)

Comment: Could you specify that inputs must be padded

Comment: Added that in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 45 bytes

```
;=aP;=bP Wa;O+A I>a bAaAb"\";=aGa 1La=bGb 1Lb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLSeS4Gq3bGSKZIGijgALyeUD@BJZlkG1suyTZFiWsH89193zopFtcpe75YNlzTzd0/1MT3ePiXq3UfTtVZJF6XIS7xXlJJm/vhs2zZE0GdeGovJxEa@A8iS7rQ2VyUxgJvE0yWKWpiydZ7f00dSjH84@vmde9Xr14ZL51es/Di7ZbvV6dPaO/Vy9Xn5kXgU@Or0ysGcfTw3ox7P3B1d/twvObPxosz@9v3E9e3AFy4rJ6C7MWYdXAiYKbNUqhkO2W82dHX7CyQwmyaOvDL/v7a1gcBnCoJuASVOOwBrm7fn5KYHwY5@c7KNvhiGXxwIA8oat92G6jDm/zka82SQ/YFeuR8Fl6/D8yP42CMKLQTC@YJ/CwXn3gJ0MQzY@CA/GrZsWzB2HzDsNg/HxGJ7jbxxkWgOhpgN64nDGAlQ4aDZh1UWYF7HN2VOzkWQlSwbNBoySBQ7rTJdZBCMkHMF7OVs4xSK79kfBk@u4z6CjkYA6wsPTxYE3b1B9smAPd0kZF4swipsN@J7GNoyDuC3McFjrprzJbqY3OXt6vh7ZvP@qxcmURjJltrY2YNYrizOhQo1uwehNBsPdrhgBOxtxWsTmwLMwJ7qLo9/YdJ6zbDkbx3kh7WF2UkyS26RUWmF1dMdztEfi2WGey7qsIy3vdjnrMcu1YAm0NOEsj8tlnjEVM0KMwmawasN9mCfhOI2VFWBEOn@IczuC9ZQh7OtXpoyL6C0iIj5bXNKTbHA9CTwH9ijQwyvW4SmU0QqQbLJc2LilTHLaY/C2brDICYXQJsy4sazKppYlNg2EwQNtFAMlkEPgO1i2CIuSlXcxKAvzEsByAzqKUdzQiKMnyljjaL1oLHx6nDa6UZFB5mPolsk8A7MxYt0RmBYpRorlYoGEcxVVasSk34w/oN0gG3WoUF5kEMeQzzBypeWClQ@WPvRi4AgHMLf1MaehmSrIKB0KV220G00N03Qe2buu43F0EIe1E@RgtkzTMH80Ha3259LYngtLW0YLSvlltiJNS3i4hEwKmzw9OHz77suvW6e/nBsOm2rHyUa9/rrerZri45OrFzSWcU4qw2zC/rUM1SuqvTeX2FlfQhBwbGkuTjZwQcK7deE65plSZb7McIcGMid3ynlhq1xJBwBCu0wiRrPj5fTa3x1JO8RGtyk9aAOKBRyrcmoDFPzfTtNJS@UdqkkOKllVAIdCKxDVTqxfw@0xb6fuJzqPsbjPWmW@jFsQg3ocQxLGpyFkEJxoYWS1KhLQT/RdliWi4/Pb@TyFmXGdgRd9rdz6nkOdH/fINHO8ZmaKNmZ/qY0QtOU8TW3TVIe5DlSI/8HkbM1krMLvDy7OHKzFItDg9eTac10XwglcgVf1ViR/xJ9Lho@BEaOGt8gAvDn44dPnTuCpko4ZDqs6PujTF48dABydnB522BSS46ChQ1uuh2k4ChdOGmfUARhcqa5JcAbn7iUyVgWxNmFpw4JjJ9RLQC3eIy4GUFQSnNR5I5otVnaASEpGVQpBmpIRLlM8JGV0Z3eAmbUmCzhi8i/COmUdWH2GqwhAgIRimwZZmLfJKaleNoq1kOUDqsIVgrrRMsfSRQ3p9Yg/VWEGDRTldrHwJSxc151DxrN52/19in8V8gKQoFVwdBuXKfSSdpv2so07hCVykmR8kExtm/YTG4LoLkdbHIhTzsU2B@5go63w4NQGiPUOxXqic8RsIAkZKHuRJJk7KyvfVv4IvJ55V82gpEmxxnwBDEYDxF@wmC/izDYWdlp5i1oFsCqYiUoJ8Rj47u7PNC6bC1t0JFMwfYJOQQsHIetgfwdw6B3oDdeApVV42TDIugG1QnhiAckl3aCH1iKqUUMnYL7Zs1Q0Vp78Cp7Ev0Mbh6d9zc@t2q7TlWELM9ka8HQtPGCVtM6LAf/F6ss@cUMg68wnK1DrjNpiG2sQV0VoONzlVWO5lg6V6BU1h/Z2gYL1w7AuDHRC62OuC5mUtyqomsDyEoeZVPtSCZM1y9wBmVskC@cVC3gwxMUHSRP7WaOOtdt0z@r1EDoSbe4NtdsNZdb2604B9tjwxpk6arlh/rIs1O7rmBC9njCoqw2iPAn5ElMyhpaxPaKbbtR3W1xaEQ19P1Ox5Is9x/6XDoPYAELhMJ7yQHnp882hGoWlesiu0@tWNHH1HXVx6EYdepYyR0i/emvRaUQ7tup1e4VQp9qdDSyslucNPHTWeBD7uomF2QbXOoQJTCUkADXIpgwZWDdwyUPQoNcjfZIoKpmrGy0YLWun/813iXmzmZjt7wptbxb6J7FZc0hcHWjMN70cSNoF6wHreZplwgL1HpyzngdnzDPB/g@i9yA91rBBgFBat69GXEU5Ee0PXcm1z6ld6QTEf3P1QNAkuQJ3BEqwWGLgO14Z7uI8tgqWzaGHTtIyydhD@Ai8sckc7qRlfBvnILOYZ3FWJiHeIuAkz9lDzO7C@xiAUhHCSzYLsyWEz@NrHEXvxsg4UEFMFMu0xB8NaHGd8BSkZ2LUkiuUmXIasqIe9b2MdF82RMP2aiiX7udhirXxEbzOJmk8YV8qs79oLU/4TTRmxiKVM0NU1uupd07whoR2DNOfdR7co2BdKXyY9Gp5MahnxX1mHv498xigaF/@HNdmArDPao0iDTrMyIaowxWSquT6og4gdiuAamN0QUM4lBha88m8z2bxLFpgmGVs@GX//3Vl@Be4MlSubG3wJZC@SFf2X2ZfrLrBZJzeZzWArxG@KqBbm@ysXrR7KvOYCrR57Sr9oS@basO@KSlTiZb/@t/IyxxkqNHyA6tvomtt7io2qLJuffqHLzKqt61uMohr1G4zOhUSBjWOgpq0kSZRAhHdrhYTJn8C98SvXmajWfOOmb2LFDupd@0INeT3/f6OQcuxuDIERofVNQvQ@h0pkxcPR5@FnVpDeyWIXlE6WC15/qaSt8N1H@Br6V0a/A8NERqGT9yKSDf/uh0yeyMfPMRVux42SdQgiPgXk/QgRFeeBFh9Ek9DSJLgmeowkwwmkwn9iBRGJZQpazuysOfEEc5euMWiMl0DoRuUPyTMwiTDZpWF@W3kkNJOB77fc/y5iu6X@N8d2yVr6te452/eT77nNl33J9f7Nw)

Takes two zero-padded numbers (it works with spaces as well).

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 4 bytes

```
vmax
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeWChIqVsjMV7Dm4lIytLS0VFJQMjIwtFD6X5abWPG/oCgzrwQoYW5kaACUMTAwNzBUUgBJKUCljI2A4obmaIIGFiBzTA2wCRsYmSIL/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
§
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVBNyZmb290ZXI9SiZpbnB1dD0lNUIxJTJDNyUyQzIlMkMxJTJDMCU1RCUwQSU1QjAlMkMwJTJDNyUyQzAlMkMxJTVEJmZsYWdzPQ==)

I/O as pre-padded lists of digits. Built-in for "dyadic maximum".